# Componente primefaces não renderizou como esperado

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, o campo de digitar o texto não está no layout do primefaces. Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo agora segue o meu arquivo .xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:panelGroup id="cadastro">
            <h:form id="cad">
                <p:panel>
                    <h:outputText value="Cadastro de Habilidades"
                        style="font-size:18px;fontweight:bold" />
                    <p:messages />
                    <p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="ui-noborder">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Nome " />
                        <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.nome}" size="50" />
                        <p:message for="nome" errorClass="invalid" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
</html>
```

O driver está nas dependências do Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Douglas,

Sua página XHTML começa com o componente **h:panelGroup** antes do **form**:

```
<h:panelGroup id="cadastro">
```

Sugiro que você coloque o formulário como primeiro elemento e utilize apenas componentes nativos do Primefaces, no seu caso eu mudaria seu código para algo assim:

```
<h:form id="formCadastro">
    <p:panel id="cadastro">
        <p:outputLabel value="Cadastro de Habilidades" />

        <p:messages/>   

        <p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="ui-noborder">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nome " />
            <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.nome}" size="50" />
            <p:message for="nome" errorClass="invalid" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

O que faz a classe de estilo **ui-noborder** do código abaixo?

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="ui-noborder">
```

Tome cuidado pois dependendo do que há nessa classe há possibilidades do estilo do seu campo texto ser sobrescrito por outras regras que tenham maior prioridade.

Você utiliza tema? Está funcionando com outros componentes?
Envie mais detalhes para que as pessoas possam entender melhor seu problema e quem sabe melhor ajudá-lo.

Espero que isso ajude...

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado, rsrs....Nem lembrava desta pergunta mais... :)

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkk pior que vi agora quer era de Maio. Valeu!  :)